# iOs - Geolocation, no cordova_plugin.js file is generated when the plugin is installed

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm having problem (as many people) to avoid the duplication of the alert asking for permissione to locate the phone.

Reading this post http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/11/2/Seeing-two-geolocation-prompts-in-a-PhoneGapCordova-application I've seen peple talking about `cordova_plugin.js`, but I don't have this file in my project.

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the plugin... Any help?

I'm running cordova 3.5.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you go into the platforms folder, you should be able to see if the plugin was successfully added. You may have to uninstall and reinstall the app itself.